# Install Adobe LightRoom on Raspberry Pi B+

Tags: software-installation

I would like to install Adobe LightRoom on to my Pi. I have the OS (Raspbian Wheezy). I tried to search, using the below command. I am not sure if can do this.

```
sudo apt-cache search lightroom
sudo apt-cache search adobe
sudo apt-get install lightroom
```

Comment: **[GIMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIMP)** is available for the pi, although I think software of this sort is going to be pretty sluggish regardless.

Comment: @goldilocks not sure if GIMP can handle RAW files, and that's usually the main reason to install LR.

Comment: @lenik Ah, not my area of expertise -- but I notice there is a `gimp-ufraw` ("gimp importer for raw camera images") as well as a [ufraw standalone](http://ufraw.sourceforge.net/) package in raspbian.  If you search for "linux RAW photo" various possibilties show up (I can't evaluate them though).  Again, methinks doing this kind of work on the pi is going to be S-L-O-W.

Comment: IMHO, this was a poorly researched question.

Answer (score 4):

you can not do that. there's no LR version that runs on Linux and there's no version that runs on ARM processors. so, give up, use your PC instead.